# Humans with Wings?

Tags: humans

In a similar world except for where humans have wings, I know that there will be many advantages.

But, I would like to know what disadvantages (for humans and Earth) will exist in this kind of scenario.

For Example:

1. The air traffic would be increased.
2. It would be hard for us to clean with towels after bathing.

etc.

Can you guys think of any other drawbacks if we had wings?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding. We solve problems, we don't discuss ideas. There are forums for that. So please state your problem.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding @ashveli. As your question is one of idea generation and discussing a concept, this is an excellent subject to be vented on [The Factory Floor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor), which is the WB SE general chat. Do pop over and say hello. :)

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You might want to have a look at already existing questions on the site to get information about your scenario and a feeling for the questions that are on-topic here. For example you can search [winged humanoids is:q](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=winged+humanoids+is%3Aq) to find questions such as [What should dwellings look like for a winged humanoid?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/42813/28789). Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

The main drawback if we have wings is that we have to trail around everywhere with useless appendages. There’s no kind of wings that can let humans actually fly — we’re much too heavy.

Comment: The next issue is that we would either not have arms (but have wings instead) or the anatomy would get _a lot_ more complicated.